# When doing a non ancestor query with a sort by key, will my result be ordered by entity groups?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to change a fair amount of entities belonging to different entity groups. 
If I do a non-ancestor query, sorted by key, like:

```
Query query = new Query( "Kind" )
                      .setFilter( ... )
                      .addSort( Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, ASC or DESC );
```

Will I always have a result ordered by entity-groups? I am planning to iterate through the
result until the parent (or grand-parent) key changes, and create a single transaction for all the entities in the same group - to avoid contention.

Will this work as expected? Any other suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Sorting by keys orders them by each entity in the ancestor list in order - eg, first by root entities, then by their children, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Kindles Queries or Ancestor Queries can only be sorted by KEY.

You are sorting by key and that is ok.

The key is a result of the PARENT+KIND+ID

Each Kind's keys is a part of the KEY. So all your results will be sorted by kind, and then by key.

From [GAE KEYS](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass)

> Every model instance has an identifying key, which includes the
>   instance's entity kind along with a unique identifier. The identifier
>   may be either a key name string, assigned explicitly by the
>   application when the instance is created, or an integer numeric ID,
>   assigned automatically by App Engine when the instance is written
>   (put) to the Datastore.